# How to convert a dictionary values to a list?

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-7, dictionary, windows-phone

In windows phone, I retrieved a table in database as dictionary in LINQ. My dictionary is like this

```
Dictionary<int, StudentTable>
```

I retrieved the table from LINQ as

```
var studentDictionary = studContext.StudentList.Select(p => new { p.RollNo, p }).AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.RollNo, kvp => kvp);
```

But I want to get all the values in the studentDictionary as a

```
List<StudentTable>
```

I know it is possible by adding each dictionary values to the list by using for loop. 
How can I do this without a loop. ?
 Is there any other better method than a loop?

Thanks

Comment: Any other method would internally do a loop anyway, so why don't you write the loop and have more freedom about what goes in the list and what not?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `studentDictionary.Values`.

PS: The same works for the keys, using `studentDictionary.Keys`

Comment: ...and if you really want a List<T>: `studentDictionary.Values.ToList()`

Comment: Except that `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.ValueCollection` is an `ICollection<T>`, not an `IList<T>`. Easily solved, though; call `.ToList()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary contains `Value` which is an object of type `StudentTable`. You can select that from the dictionary and apply `ToList` method.

```
var list = studentDictionary.Values.ToList();
```

or

```
var list = studentDictionary.Select(r => r.Value).ToList();
```